# The Complement of Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I address and the following question? More importantly than the answer I would like to know the reasoning for addressing the question.

$A = \{-6, 3, 4, 5\}, B = \{-6, 5, 13\}, U = A \cup B \cup \{12, -2, -4\}$

In which case, I was reasoning that the universe omega is the union of A, B, and U = {-4, 3, 4, 5, -6, 12, 13, -2}. If so, then the complement is the empty set.

Which of the following is the correct output for complemenent_of_union(A, B, U)?

A. $\{-6, -2, 3, 4, 13\}, \{-6, -2, 4, 12\}$

B. $\{-4, -2\}, \{-6, -4, 3, 5, 13\}$

C. $\{-6, 3, 4, 5, 13\}, \{-4, -2, 12\}$

Does the De'Morgans law for the complement of the unions result in the empty set here? U contains A, B and {12, -2, -4}. Since the empty set is not one of the available answers I am wrong. 
Thank you.

$\overline{A\cup B \cup U} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{U}$

Comment: First of all, you have to wrie the set resulting from the "union" of A,B and U.

Comment: Second, the "complement" is relative to an "ambience" set : the universe : what is the universe here ?

Comment: The given answers are all wrong because the answer is not two sets.  If U is that universal set thing, the answer is the empty set.  As this problem is  not a computer program, there is no  output.  That last line is correct.